# Deploying File On iOS Device delphi xe

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe

I try to deploy file on iOS from delphi xe5 mobile app, I set remote path in deployment to "startUp\Documents", it is OK on the simulator but on the device there is the following file structure:

```
MyApp.app
+Documents
+MyApp.app
++Startup
+++Documents
++++MyDBFile
```

As you can see from above MyDBFile is deployed in the wrong folder, when I copy the file to the first Documents folder everything is OK, I tried `.\Startup\Documents` and `.\Documents` and `\Documents` but nothing changed. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set "StartUp\Documents\" (case is important!)

And after get this file:

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'filename')
```

More information read on Embarcadero Doc Wiki: [Loading and Deploying Files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_iOS_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)